# To get the extrinsic data from the extrinsic Hash

Tags: extrinsic, polkadot-js

When I submit a transation using the polakdot-js-api I get that the transaction is included in block number and I also receive the extrinsic hash

````
```*Tx included at block hash 0x9225abf7cb9241f543f629c4277cb7799ab90e557af8f4d17201ae1f2d625765*
*Tx hash: 0x3e2f84e2f46cb82a2491fa772d66127ec8c8c00ce15a0bfc65be31fcf400b7a5*```
````

But is it possible for me to get the data that is submitted in that particular transaction through this extrinsic-hash that I got from the above transation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could work with that. If you have the extrinsic hash and the block number than you could something like this:

```
const exampleBlockNumber = 7200920
const blockHash = await api.rpc.chain.getBlockHash(exampleBlockNumber);
const signedBlock = await api.rpc.chain.getBlock(blockHash);
const extrinsicHash = "0xeb8f2a5af4a82a237e7e270ed6bd51ce82bb9253802259fd0fdb24212fe65260"
signedBlock.block.extrinsics.forEach(async (ex, index) => {
    if (extrinsicHash === ex.hash.toHex()) {
        console.log(index, ex.toHuman());
        const { method: { args, method, section } } = ex;
        console.log(`${section}.${method}(${args.map((a) => a.toString()).join(', ')})`);
    }
});
```

For this specific example you would get this output:

```
1 {
  isSigned: true,
  method: {
    args: { dest: [Object], value: '39.5536 DOT' },
    method: 'transfer',
    section: 'balances'
  },
  era: { MortalEra: { period: '64', phase: '18' } },
  nonce: '0',
  signature: '0x56344710ae648a1da40e2c1a1159c73fdbd7d522af01f1fd330fb6bedc4db615ca983d69fcf7cdf7376ab59fd4c492a711cc64bba48d6ae23762d95176071a0c',
  signer: { Id: '13a9ccJQrJZdLsdisnL31uuApQmNfGd3d3fmGdqLPiBiW8jP' },
  tip: '0'
}
balances.transfer(13Hwdzi6jkXtBWTSU5de5gC93hDog23pdqd59SPZ7s9zXVNL, 395536044985)
```

Comment: yeh it worked. thanks

Comment: Hey what if I have only the extrinsic hash and not the block number?

Comment: @Bukks no you need both ext_hash and block number. See this https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/why-could-we-find-the-same-transaction-hash-in-3-different-blocks

Comment: is there any property in ex to get result of transfer ?